Turn off voice of "Your computer remotely control by **" ScreenSharing MacOS
I using 2 laptops, both on MacOS with ScreenSharing.
And when I trying to use second laptop without VNC/ScreenSharing,I hearing voice with attention.
"Your compture remotely control blah blah"
How can I disable it ?

Voiceover can be turned off in several ways.

https://support.apple.com/guide/voiceover/turn-voiceover-on-or-off-vo2682/mac

Pressing Command-F5 might be the first to try.

Voice over is turned off at both laptops.
I'll try Command-F5 later, thanks)

Command-F5 not working @bmike

I wonder if you are using an Apple keyboard connected directly to the Mac generating the speech?

No, I just using main laptop keyboard.
Other laptop sitting in other room.
Main is mine, second is provided by empolyeer

@Sam Did you find a solution? The voice is very annoying and loud!

@Josh Regrettably, the alarm persists, causing annoyance.
